# Django (custom)form unicode object has no attrbute 'get'

Tags: python, django, forms, unicode

I have seen several posts about the "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'" error but nothing fixed my problem.

I am trying to use a formiew to redirect to my download page.

i override the form_valid function from the formview to redirect to my /download url

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
       clean_form = form.cleaned_data
       print clean_form.get('starttime')
       return reverse('accesslogs_download', kwargs={'domain': self.get_object().domainname}) + "?a=b&b=c"
```

this should redirect to :
"/download?a=b&b=c " but i get redirected to my formView with the following error:

> AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'

My full Traceback is:

> Internal Server Error: /serverlogs/business.sla.nl/accesslogs/realtime/view
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/jasperf/.virtualenvs/servicepanel/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 131, in get_response
>
> response = middleware_method(request, response)
>
> File "/home/jasperf/.virtualenvs/servicepanel/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 32, in process_response
>
> if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
>   AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'

How can i fix this and get redirected to /download?a=b&b=c

Note: i don't plan to use the variable a or b, but when u can get to that url i can put my own variable there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't return the result of `reverse` - that's just a string. You need to return a redirect; normally, you could use `reverse` instead and pass the URL arguments directly, but in your case you want to append query params, so you still need to call it explicitly.

```
destination = reverse('accesslogs_download', kwargs={'domain': self.get_object().domainname}) + "?a=b&b=c"
return redirect(destination)
```

Comment: This is literally perfect. I got 2 things mixed up. form_valid calls redirect(self.get_success_url()). while i thought i was overriding the get_success in some fancy way, i forgot the redirect.